# How to pass multiple locals to a nested partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview, partials

This should be extremely straightforward and well documented, and I've done it several times, although there's something that's still killing me.

I have a structure of partials calling nested partials.

At some point one `render` call needs to pass an extra variable to the partial, although the rendering of the partial fails with a:

```
undefined local variable or method `<variable name>' for #<#<Class:....>
```

Here's my code for calling the `render`:

```
= f.simple_fields_for :orders do |c|
  = render partial: "fields", locals: {f: c, step: f.object.step}
```

though this doesn't work either:

```
= f.simple_fields_for :orders do |c|
  = render "fields", f: c, step: f.object.step
```

here's where the exception is raised:

```
f.input :quantity, input_html: {step: step}
```

the form_for comes from the `views/lists/_form.html.haml`:

```
= simple_form_for( @order, :html => { :multipart => true }, defaults: { input_html: { class: 'input-medium' } } ) do |f|
```

`f` is then passed to `views/orders/_order_forms.html` via

```
= render "orders/order_forms", f: f
```

here's the exception with trace:

```
    ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `step' for #<#<Class:0x007fe0479ba2b0>:0x007fe04256a930>):

application trace:
    app/views/orders/_fields.html.haml:9:in `_app_views_orders__fields_html_haml___1860431911739668171_70300581339300'
    app/views/orders/_order_forms.html.haml:30:in `_app_views_orders__order_forms_html_haml__2241963939037094859_70300612771460'
    app/views/lists/_form.html.haml:48:in `block in _app_views_lists__form_html_haml__1669043093238943449_70300583658680'
    app/views/lists/_form.html.haml:3:in `_app_views_lists__form_html_haml__1669043093238943449_70300583658680'
    app/views/lists/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_lists_new_html_erb___1563391577928218041_70300593681100'
    app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:67:in `new'
```

framework trace (the end of it):

```
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:265:in `render_partial'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:238:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:237:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:41:in `render_partial'
actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:27:in `render'
haml (4.0.3) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:10:in `block in render_with_haml'
haml (4.0.3) lib/haml/helpers.rb:89:in `non_haml'
haml (4.0.3) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:10:in `render_with_haml'
cocoon (1.2.0) lib/cocoon/view_helpers.rb:40:in `block in render_association'
```

I've had a similar issue before and I resolved it in simplifying the passing of locals.. but now I would really like to understand what's going on.

any clue?

I'm using:

```
ruby 2.0.0p297
rails 3.2.8
```

Thanks a lot in advance..

**UPDATE**

I have debugged my view and figured that the `order_forms` is being rendered twice, the first time `step` is not set, while in the second rendering it is set correctly.

I'm not sure why this happens, but I managed to work it around with adding the following line to my `fields.html.haml`.

```
-step = step || 1
```

basically I put a default value to step, in case it's not defined, so that at the first execution the rendering doesn't crash, while at the second execution it works properly.

The page looks as expected now. Although I'm thinking about the waste of resources when rendering the stuff twice.

any idea on why that happens?

Comment: Just a tip: If you are passing f, you don't need `f.object.step`.

Comment: yeah, thanks, I'm passing `c` and call it `f`, I just need `step` from the `f.object`

Comment: Assuming `f` is the form builder object, based on `f.object.step` your call should probably be `render partial: "fields", locals: {f: f, step: f.object.step}`?

Comment: I've just added the line that generates the form builder object `c` to clarify. thanks :)

Comment: Can you post your trace? That might give us the clue.

Comment: ups, no sorry, where's the trace? you mean the list of file names from my project?

Comment: This is fine.  You should be able to see them in the browser when an exception occurs.  There should be links to them e.g Application, Framework, Full.  But you can grab them from your environment log file as well.

Comment: It looks like the your `f.object` does not have `step` attribute.  Have you verified that?

Comment: yep, verified, it has the `step`

Comment: Can you post your `form_for` declaration as well?

Comment: Looks correct, and I can't find anything.  I tested similar scenario with simple form and wizard steps and it's working for me in rails 3.2.  Instead of accessing `step` directly in your partial, have you checked `c.object.step` (should be the same result, but give it a try)

Comment: thank you for your guess, `c.object` and `f.object` are different objects, and `c.object` doesn't know about step.

Comment: I think I red some time ago that this was a bug of rails having to do specifically with locals in nested partials, but it seems that I'm the only one experiencing it.

Comment: OFF TOPIC: you are using a version of rails that is susceptible to security exploit, recommend upgrading to the latest rails 3.2 version ASAP - see https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aweblog.rubyonrails.org&q=security

Comment: thanks, I've updated to 3.2.14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After finding out that the code was run twice, I went investigating who else was running it.

and I realized that just few lines before there was the call to cocoon function `link_to_add_association`

of course it's not only the official `render` rendering the partial but also that function needs to render it.

I have added the line:

```
:render_options => {:locals => {:step => step }},
```

to my `link_to_add_association` function call and removed the workaround and now everything works as expected.

The more modern version analogous to this would be:

```
render_options: {locals: {step: step }},
```

a bit shorter, and looking better.

Comment: I literally just had this exact problem and it was doing my head in - It seemed as though the second local was being ignored but it was my link_to_add_association later in my code which wasn't passing the local which was causing the error! I just added an `if defined?(my_variable) then my_variable end` in my partial so I didn't have to make sure it was included every time I render it.